# join columns but print all lines in both files

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

Imagine I have file1:

```
2 luke
3 matthew
4 mark
7 john
```

and I have

```
1 chicken
2 beef
5 lamb
6 fish
```

I want the following:

```
1 [tab]chicken
2 luke[tab]beef
3 matthew[tab]
4 mark[tab]
5 lamb[tab]
6 fish[tab]
7 [tab]john
```

kind like "join" but I want the other columns as well. I know I can do it using 3 "comm"s and fiddle with it using sort but is there a single command to do it ?

Comment: Your output doesn't match up. `id 1` is not in `file1` so output shows `1 [tab]chicken`, but `id 7` **is in** `file1` so why is your output `7 [tab]john`. It should be `7 john[tab`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use a few options with `join`:

```
join -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e $'\t' tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
```

`-a1` and `-a2` tell `join` to output lines from both file 1 and file 2 which cannot be paired (so all lines from both files are included). `-o` specifies three columns in the output: the join field (0), the second column from the first file, and the second column from the second file. `-e` specifies a string to fill empty fields (fields not found). `$'\t'` is a `bash` extension; a more compatible way of passing a tab character is `-e $(printf '\t')`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using AWK:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; i++; next}{ b[$1]=$2; i++} END { OFS="\t"; for (n=1;n<i;++n) print n, a[n], b[n] }' file1 file2
```

This goes through `file1` (first `{block}`) and `file2` (second `{block}`, building arrays indexed by the number in the first column. Then at the end it prints out all the values in each array.

Answer (score 0):

This fills in empty fields with a tab, but the fields are still space delimited.

```
join  -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e $'\t' file1 file2
```

```
1    chicken
2 luke beef
3 matthew   
4 mark  
5    lamb
6    fish
7 john
```

To view the whitespace characters, pipe the output into `| od -c`

To achieve exactly your desired output, use awk:

```
awk '
    {
        ids[$1]
        if (NR==FNR) 
            f1[$1]=$2
        else 
            f2[$1]=$2
    } 
    END {
        n = asorti(ids, sorted_ids)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "%d %s\t%s\n", sorted_ids[i], f1[sorted_ids[i]], f2[sorted_ids[i]]
    }
' file1 file2
```

```
1   chicken
2 luke  beef
3 matthew   
4 mark  
5   lamb
6   fish
7 john
```

Comment: Good solution, though if you change the `\t` to `[tab]` you'll notice it doesn't match up to OP's requirement of padding tabs that are not present in either file. **Update** Though it seems OP's requested output is incorrect and the one you have is what it should be.

Comment: Good eye. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{print $1, $2, a[$1];delete a[$1];next} {print $1, $2, ""}
     END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' OFS='\t' f2 f1|sort -nk1
1   chicken
2   luke    beef
3   matthew
4   mark
5   lamb
6   fish
7   john
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with `awk`. Just replace `[tab]` with `\t`.

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1] = $2 "[tab]"; next }
($1 in a) { a[$1] = a[$1] $2; next }
{ a[$1] = "[tab]" $2 }
END {
    n = asorti(a, s);
    for (x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        print s[x], a[s[x]]}
' file1 file2
1 [tab]chicken
2 luke[tab]beef
3 matthew[tab]
4 mark[tab]
5 [tab]lamb
6 [tab]fish
7 john[tab]
```